# Python Launcher: Unexpected version of Python runs by default

Tags: python, environment-variables, version, python-3.8

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.8 installed.

I want to use the Windows Python Launcher (py.exe) to double-click on .py files and have them run automatically with Python 2.7 unless I specifically start my .py file with the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/python3.8`

The [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) says this should work as expected since the default environment variable PY_PYTHON has a value of 2, so the Python Launcher will run scripts with Python 2.7 by default.

It doesn't work as expected. It runs any script with Python 3.8 by default. Moreover, I don't have PY_PYTHON at all in my environment variables.

Why could that be?

I want to give users easy instructions to set up their environment to use the Python Launcher in this way and I'd prefer not have them go through manually creating a new PY_PYTHON=2 environment variable. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` is a UNIX/Linux shebang. You shouldn't expect it to work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` at the top of Python 2 files and `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` at the top of Python 3 files. This not only provides the intended effect of running the correct version but this also informs other programmers what version of Python it is written in.

Comment: [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/): "For example, a shebang line of '#! /usr/bin/python' should work even though there is unlikely to be an executable in the relative Windows directory "\usr\bin". This means that many scripts can use a single shebang line and be likely to work on both Unix and Windows without modification." @KlausD.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem as there are too many files already developed in Python 2 and I have little control over them. I just need some users to keep Python 2 as their default and not mess with that but be able to run some solutions I developed for them in Python 3. I need to just point them to a direct link to install Python 3.8 then in some easy one-off steps have them make .py files open (when double-clicked) with the Python Launcher that comes with it. I thought the purpose of that tool was to make this easy. Maybe I'm missing some easy alternative?